# Passing end-user details from client to real backend endpoint

Tags: wso2, api-manager

how can I Passing end-user details from client to real backend endpoint
I try the following URL but doesn't work with me
[Passing end-user details from client to real backend endpoin](http://lalajisureshika.blogspot.com/2013/06/passing-end-user-details-from-client-to.html)

Comment: post your xml config

Comment: could you please explain me more

Comment: Go to [ESB_HOME]repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\tasks\ and open the file [task_name].xml and paste in your question the xml content.

Comment: i didn't use ESB! i use API management

Comment: What do you means by `doesn't work`?